# Order by, distinct and select top 5 results with linq

Tags: c#, database, performance, linq, service

Hi everyone I'm trying to select 5 distinct records from the db but I need to be ordered and distinct. I am looking for most efficient way to do so. The thing is that Distinct() method messes up ordering, So I am trying to achieve it by grouping them, but it seems that grouping also messes up the ordering. Maybe someone would have a good solution?

That's my current try.

```
public async Task<List<RecentProjectDto>> GetMostRecentProjects(int userId, int companyId)
    {
        using (var db = _dbFactory.Create())
        {


            var recentProjects = await db.ScheduleLogs
                .OfType<WorkLog>()
                .Where(x => x.UserId == userId)
                .Where(x => x.User.CompanyId == companyId)
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.End)
                .GroupBy(x => new { x.ProjectId, x.Project.Name, x.Project.Key, x.Project.Colour })
                .Select(x => new RecentProjectDto
                {
                   ProjectId = x.ProjectId,
                    ProjectName = x.Project.Name,
                    ProjectKey = x.Project.Key,
                    Colour = x.Project.Colour
                })
                .Take(5)
                .ToListAsync();
            return recentProjects;


        }
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest trying to add the sorting column to result like `.OrderByDesc(x => x.End).Distinct().Select(x => new{x.End, dto = new RecentProjectDto{....}}).Take(5).ToList()` and remove the `GroupBy`

Comment: Your `.OrderByDescending` should come after `Groupby`

Comment: @Rahul group by does not include the sorting column.

Comment: @GuruStron Yes true, am going by the SQL order of execution

Comment: @GuruStron I tried it, but Distinct copletely removes the ordering.

Comment: @Rahul  is ``.Distinct()`` work here for Complex object without a custom comparer?

Comment: @Rahul If I do that, I do not get Distinct values, which I am trying to achieve by grouping

Comment: @Sajid it seems there is db involved, so code is converted into SQL, and it does not care about comparer.

Comment: @KarolisPakalnis can you add generated SQL in both cases?

Comment: i think, you can change the ``select`` to : ``.Select(x=> x.First()).OrderByDescending(x => x.End)`` after grouping and delete the first ``orderby``

Comment: @GuruStron I don't know how to look at the genereated sql.

Comment: Depends on framework you use, if it's EF  you can do something like [this](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/logging-in-entityframework-core.aspx). Also you can use db profiler to see what query was sent.

Comment: @Sajid that seems something I am looking for, but how do I select my dto in this case

Comment: after ``.Take(5)``, you can use ``.Select(x => new RecentProjectDto
                {
                    ProjectId = x.ProjectId,
                    ProjectName = x.Project.Name,
                    ProjectKey = x.Project.Key,
                    Colour = x.Project.Colour
                })``

Comment: @Sajid Do you mean to have selects in query?

Comment: Yeah the last just for converting entities to ``RecenProjectDto``

Comment: I thought so, and I actually tried it, but in this cas the query just hangs and doesn't get executed without any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does something like this work?

```
var recentProjects = await db.ScheduleLogs
            .OfType<WorkLog>()
            .Where(x => x.UserId == userId)
            .Where(x => x.User.CompanyId == companyId)              
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.ProjectId, x.Project.Name, x.Project.Key, x.Project.Colour })
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Max(a=>a.OrderDate))
            .Select(x => new RecentProjectDto
            {
                ProjectId   = x.Key.ProjectId,
                ProjectName = x.Key.Name,
                ProjectKey  = x.Key.Key,
                Colour      = x.Key.Colour
            })
            .Take(5)
            .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Strange. Either this is throwing some exception that isn't being displayed, or it is taking a very long time which probably means you are using some linq provider that is performing some operation in memory and hence pulling far more data from your database than you want. You don't mention which type of database you are using, but if it is MSSQL, you could try downloading Linqpad and test the query against both Linq2Sql and EF and it will show you the generated sql.

Comment: Yeah thought it's weird, but I wthink I am getting some kind of error which is not being logged. I'm development db which is does not have many records, and yes, it is MSSQL.

Comment: Okay, I was using Jetbrains Rider and it would not give me any error, but switched to VS but this would not give me distinct records(Projects) in this case.

Comment: I am not sure why did it not work first time, I might have pasted something wrong from clipboard, but it actually worked. Thanks!